# passing argument directly with member or with separate variable

Tags: c++, c++11, unreal-engine4

I was wondering if theres a difference between these two examples:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh>MeshAsset(TEXT("StaticMesh'/Game/Sphere.Sphere'"));
 UStaticMesh* Asset = MeshAsset.Object;
 BuildingStaticMesh->SetStaticMesh(Asset);
```

Instead of :

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh>MeshAsset(TEXT("StaticMesh'/Game/Sphere.Sphere'"));
 BuildingStaticMesh->SetStaticMesh(MeshAsset.Object);
```

Are these two the same or not?

Comment: They look equivalent to me.

Comment: You could check this out on godbolt. I wouldn't wonder if the generated asm is identical (assuming, of course, with `-O2` or `-O3`).

Comment: AFAIK, such local variables don't hurt in any way concerning generated code. (They shouldn't on any serious modern compiler.) I justice to use or not to use them always considering readability of code but nothing else. I fiddled a little bit on godbolt: [Example on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2zMEi2). The relevant call (`print()`) seems to be inlined in both cases (indepedent of whether local variable is there or not).